# Spherically Symmetric Spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, symmetry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I have been studying the Schwarzschild metric $g$ and its derivation.

The starting point is to assume the spacetime it describes is *spherically symmetric*. This means that the algebra of its Killing vectors contains an $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ subalgebra. In Carroll's textbook he states that using Frobenius' theorem the integral curves of the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ subalgebra's Killing vectors foliate the space into 2-spheres, at which point we can use the natural coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$ on these 2-spheres and the remaining two coordinates $(a,b)$ to label which sphere we are on. As we know the metric of a 2-sphere, we can immediately write down the metric tensor for constant $(a,b)$ to be of the form

$$ g = f(a,b) \text{d}\Omega^2 $$

where

$$ \text{d}\Omega = \text{d}\theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \text{d}\phi^2 $$

### My Question

How do I know the foliation generated by the $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ sub algebra generates 2-spheres that have the same metric as the usual 2-spheres embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? All we know is that the foliation will generate two dimensional surfaces and I am happy to assign these surfaces the coordinates $(\theta,\phi)$, and call them 'spheres', but are they truly spheres in the sense that I can assign them *exactly* the same metric as the $S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$? It is always stressed when studying general relativity that Euclidean geometry is no longer valid; 'Straight lines' have to be redefined and they may not necessarily remain parallel etc. so how can I say the spheres are the same as $S^2$?

Comment: The foliating spheres are maximally symmetric by construction. Hence they are either spheres, euclidean planes or hyperboloids. Of these only a sphere has so(3) as its Killing algebra.

Comment: @mmeent Please don't use comments for answers.  We've all done it by accident (or not), but it's not how Physics SE is intended to work.  The reply cannot be accepted if it's a comment and it leaves questions (as far as the system and search is concerned) unanswered.